# Is $\mathcal F(X)\times X$ homeomorphic to $ \mathcal F(X)$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a separable metric space, and let $\mathcal F(X)$ be the set of all non-empty finite subsets of $X$.  The Vietoris topology on $\mathcal F(X)$ is generated by the basic open sets:  $$\textstyle \langle U_0,\ldots,U_{k-1}\rangle=\{F\in \mathcal F(X): F\subset \bigcup_{i<k} U_i\text{ and }F\cap U_i\neq \varnothing\text{ for each }i<k\},$$
where $k<\omega$ and $U_0,\ldots,U_{k-1}$ are non-empty open subsets of $X$.

The obvious mapping $\mathcal F(X)\times X\to \mathcal F(X)$ defined by $\langle F,x\rangle\mapsto F\cup \{x\}$ is continuous, open, onto, and finite-to-one.

Is it true that $\mathcal F(X)\times X$ is homeomorphic to $\mathcal F(X)$?

Answer (score 1):

Not in general: if $X$ is a finite discrete space of cardinality $n$, then $$|\mathscr{F}(X)\times X|=n(2^n-1)\,,$$ which is greater than $2^n-1=|\mathscr{F}(X)|$ if $n>1$.

Comment: What about an infinite example?

Comment: @D.S.Lipham: Don’t know yet; I’ll have to think about that a bit.

Comment: @D.S.Lipham I think for $X=\omega$ it does hold, and for $X=\Bbb Q$ too. Maybe $\Bbb R$ is an example? Would be tricky to prove..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Would be good to know for those spaces, as I'm mainly interested in the problem when $X$ is an infinite  topological group.

Comment: For $X=\omega$, both $\mathcal{F}(X) \times X$ and $\mathcal{F}(X)$ are countable and discrete so homeomorphic to $X$ again. For $X=\Bbb Q$ both are countable metric without isolated points so homeomorphic to $X$ too. It's only for $X=\Bbb R$ that I doubt (we have an infinite-dimensional $\mathcal{F}(X)$ then, so it can get harder..)

Comment: @D.S.Lipham For $\Bbb R$ it also holds as both are homeomorphic to $\ell^2_f$, as defined in [this paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82292689.pdf). I still doubt it holds for all $X$, but for very nice spaces we can sometimes show it.